# How can I draw seamless curve using android graphics ?

Tags: android, graph, curve-fitting, bezier

I want to draw seamless curve using Android graphics using like followings

```
 canvas.quadTo(.....);
```

Android reference said that this method using Bezier curve

but this method don't support drawing curve which have more than three points

P1 , P2 , P3 , P4 , P5

How can I draw curve like followings?

> [image: Matlab]

I heard this is "Nonlinear Curve Fitting".

Is there available curve fitting library for android ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While for iPhone you have the [DataAnalysis](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/dataanalysis/id375603883), for Android you can use [Google Analytics SDK v2](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/) for what you have in mind.

Here is an [example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/gdataAnalyticsCharts) of a query:

```
var lineChart = getChartObj();
lineChart.setParams(barChart.getParams());
lineChart.setParam('cht', 'lc');
lineChart.setParam('chm', '');
var lineChartURL = paramsToURL(chartData.chartParams, chartData.baseURL);
drawChart('visitorDiv',lineChartURL);
```

You may find interesting to check more details on charts to specifically match the [model](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/line_charts) you want to plot.

Another alternative you can also consider is QML using Line Graph with [Qt Quick](http://blog.sebasgo.net/blog/2012/09/26/line-graphs-for-qt-quick/):

```
Graph.LineGraph {
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height - legend.height - parent.spacing
    model: learningProgressModel

    dimensions: [
        Graph.Dimension {
            id: accuracyDimension
            dataColumn: 5
            color: "#ffb12d"
            maximumValue: 1.0
            label: i18n("Accuracy")
            unit: "%"
            unitFactor: 100
        },
        Graph.Dimension {
            id: charactersPerMinuteDimension
            dataColumn: 6
            color: "#38aef4"
            maximumValue: 400
            label: i18n("Characters per Minute")
        }
    ]
}
```

Octave for Android may also be [interesting](http://code.google.com/p/addi/wiki/FAQ), specially if you want to have a wide option of [plotting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave) models. You can use the command [drawBezierCurve](http://octave.sourceforge.net/geometry/function/drawBezierCurve.html), providing only the points from your data:

```
points = [0 0; 3 1; -2 1; 1 0];
 drawBezierCurve(points);
 hold on
 plot(points([1 4],1),points([1 4],2),'go');
 plot(points([2 3],1),points([2 3],2),'rs');
 line(points([1 2],1),points([1 2],2),'color','k');
 line(points([3 4],1),points([3 4],2),'color','k');
 h = drawBezierCurve(points, 'discretization', 6, 'color','r');
 hold off
```

Then to achieve the [Nonlinear Curve Fitting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121212/how-to-find-curve-equation-from-data) that you want to display on your Android, just use the data or [model](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25237/Bezier-Curves-Made-Simple) that better fits your need.

Comment: and I found solution using Monotone cubic spline interpolation
provided by Google.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cd92588/core/java/android/util/Spline.java

Comment: @JindongJung - glad to hear that. if the answer helped indeed as you mentioned towards addressing your problem, you also might well check it as a correct answer.